# how to resolve 'Update operation attempted on non-updatable query'?

Tags: sql-update, sap-iq

I am working on a sybase-iq server `Sybase IQ/15.4.0.3014`

I have a working query to update one field of a table as below

```
update  table1
set     a.field1= b.some_value
from    table1 a,
        table2 b
where   a.id = b.id
```

This is working fine when I execute it from a sql session. When it is being called from a high level application, I am getting the below error for the above query

> SQL Exception code is 7301
>   Update operation attempted on non-updatable query

I am not able to find why I am getting this error. Is there any solution to amend the query. Searching on the internet is not helping much.

Have anyone come across such issue?

Comment: You may want to ask your question on http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com. It's a Q&A site for SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere, which is the backing engine for Sybase IQ.

Comment: @Graeme Thanks. will be deleting this post after asking it there.

Comment: Is this update part of a cursor ?

Comment: It was a view in my case .. which I overlooked.. leading to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You attempted an insert, update, or delete operation on a query that is implicitly read-only. You're trying to update system table or table which cannot be changed in that manner.

[link](http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/saerrors_en11/errm192.html)

Answer (score -1):

down vote

I suggest to double check that table_name is actually a table, but not a view. If it is a view, you may see its definition with sp_helptext command, such as

> sp_helptext 'view_name'

or

> sp_helptext 'schema_name.view_name'